# How to get the last commit from HEAD in a git repository using libGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

How can I get the last Commit from the current Head?

I guess I need to get the current Branch (repo.Head), then the SHA1 (how?) and then lookup the commit using the SHA1 (how?).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I need to get the last Commit from the current Head. How can I do that?

`repo.Head` returns the current `Branch` or the repository.

A `Branch` exposes a `Tip` property which points to the latest `Commit`.

Thus:

- `repo.Head.Tip` will return the latest commit of the current `Head`.
- `repo.Head.Tip.Id` the sha of this `Commit`.

> I couldnt find a Testcase which helps me out

You can peek at **[this test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/a3a989aae7aea97568f34b9b2153b85a97267346/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BranchFixture.cs#L120-L136)** which leverages this kind of code to retreive the sha of the latest commit of the branch pointed at by Head.

Comment: Thanks! Another quick question: do you know if libGit2Sharp support git-revert?

Comment: git-revert -> not supported yet. This requires `merge` feature which is not fully finalized in libgit2.